# Python/Tkinter seems to skip lines of code

Tags: python, tkinter

### This is a part of the program:

```
def WhileLoop():
    Indicators()
    subheading()

    global pcb_num
    global Firm
    Firm = 1
    global Soft7
    Soft = 1
    global pcb_mast
    while pcb_mast >= 1:
        global pcb_num
        global relay
        relay = 1
        #=========================Ammend Visual Key Indicator=========================
        while relay <= 4:
            count = int(relay / 2)
            print(count)
            counter = Label(BodyFrame,
                            text=count,
                            relief="raised",
                            font="helvetica 79",
                            bg="#b3f3c2",
                            width=2,
                            height=1)
            counter.place(relx=0.749, rely=0.5)
            delay()

            if relay == 1:
                firmware()
                if Firm == 1:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f6bc0c")  #  Yellow
                else:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f9042c")  #  Red
            elif relay == 2:
                software()
                if Soft == 1:
                    b_1.config(bg="#71c208")
                else:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f9042c")
```

---

The while loops work and the program completes.  However the field 'counter' does not display on each cycle but does display when the while loop emds.  Looking at the print(counter) when the program ends shows the right numbers.  Also, the 'config' instructions do the same, ie they do not change the colours when instructed but change then when the while loop ends.  I should add that the while loop is in a different Frame to the counter and the fields b_1 are also in a different frame (all are made global).
This has baffled me.

I need the counter and the colours in b_1 to change with each loop .

Comment: Try `counter.update_idletasks()` after the `counter.place` line. If that does what you expected from the counter, do that for all the widgets after you change their state in the while loop. Also if you share the whole code I can test it myself

Comment: Hi....That is absolutely brilliant, thank you, thank you, thank you.  I included this line and now it all works.

Comment: Hi... Good to know that it works. Now I posted it as an answer so you can tick it

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to use `while` loops in `tkinter` GUI code.  The `mainloop` isn't being called as the loop executes and the GUI is therefore unable to respond to any events.  Use `w.after` instead.

Also in the code above the counter label is recreated each time through the loop.  Only create it once and use `config` to amend the text as you've used it to amend the background colours.

As `relay` isn't set within the while loop I assume it must be set by some external process.  In the code below it's set in a parallel `after` routine.  Hopefully the framework below can help you apply `after` to your code.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label0 = tk.Label( root, text = "Count: " )
label1 = tk.Label( root, text = "Relay: " )

label0.grid()
label1.grid()

background = [ 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'white', 'gray' ]
relay = 0

def counter_update( count ):
    count += 1
    label0.config( text = f'Count is : {count}',
                   bg = background[ relay ] )
    if relay <= 4:
        root.after( 1000, counter_update, count ) # The while loop equivalent.

def relay_plus():
    global relay
    relay += 1
    label1.config( text = f'Relay is : {relay}' )
    if relay <= 4:
        root.after( 4300, relay_plus ) # The while loop equivalent.

root.after( 1000, counter_update, 0 )
relay_plus()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `counter.update_idletasks()` after the counter.place line. If that does what you expected from the counter, do that for all the widgets after you change their state in the while loop.

Your code should look something like this:

```
def WhileLoop():
    Indicators()
    subheading()

    global pcb_num
    global Firm
    Firm = 1
    global Soft7
    Soft = 1
    global pcb_mast
    while pcb_mast >= 1:
        global pcb_num
        global relay
        relay = 1
        #=========================Ammend Visual Key Indicator=========================
        while relay <= 4:
            count = int(relay / 2)
            print(count)
            counter = Label(BodyFrame,
                            text=count,
                            relief="raised",
                            font="helvetica 79",
                            bg="#b3f3c2",
                            width=2,
                            height=1)
            
            counter.place(relx=0.749, rely=0.5)
            counter.update_idletasks()
            delay()

            if relay == 1:
                firmware()
                if Firm == 1:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f6bc0c")  #  Yellow
                else:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f9042c")  #  Red
                
            elif relay == 2:
                software()
                if Soft == 1:
                    b_1.config(bg="#71c208")
                else:
                    b_1.config(bg="#f9042c")
            b_1.update_idletasks()
```